# What is the best way to store some data like key-value pairs in python

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am new to python. I need to store some data from excel file in some way (instead of accessing the excel every time). My data looks like this:

| Parameter | Minvalue | Maxvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| param1 | 5 | 10 |
| param2 | 19 | 30 |
| param3 | -1 | 10 |

I need to store it and access it by referring to the parameter name.

What is the best way to do that, I have some hundreds of parameters.

Apart from accessing, I may need to update them too.

Comment: The simplest and usually best data structure to store (key,value) pairs in python is `dict`. I am too lazy to write an answer right now but see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/.

This library can also read excel files:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

For instance in you case:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

Set the index on column Parameter:

```
df.set_index('Parameter', inplace=True)
```

Now access a cell like this:

```
df.loc['param1', 'Minvalue']
# 5
```

And write to the cell:

```
df.loc['param1', 'Minvalue'] = 6

# Read value again:

df.loc['param1', 'Minvalue']
# 6
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).